# Drupal 7, how i can acces my module, and view admin page?

Tags: drupal

I installed the last version of Drupal, and its on my localhost/drupal ...
When i'm trying to go to localhost/drupal/admin its going to Server Configuration details, like a wamp page or something, and not matter which page i try to access (pages that doesn't exist) its going to this wamp Server Configuration page

1. How can i access admin page and what is the problem with this redirection?
2. i created test.module and gave it a path admin/test, when i'm trying to access it it's redirect me to same 'Server Configuration' page.

Here is my module code:

```
<?php

function test_permission() {
  return array(
    'administer blocks' => array(
      'title' => t('acess all users'),
    ),
  );
}

function test_menu() {
  $items['admin/test'] = array(
    'title' => 'Tulik module',
    'page callback' => 'tulik_page_display',
    'access arguments' => array('acess all users'),
  );

  return $items;
}

function tulik_page_display() {
    echo 'hello';
}
```

Comment: can you access the admin panel with: localhost/?q=admin/ ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drupal 7 example module, page not found, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7529513/drupal-7-example-module-page-not-found-why)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the clean url of its enabled or not from
http://localhost/drupal/?q=admin/config/search/clean-urls
i think u should enable it