# Drupal 7 example module, page not found, why?

Tags: drupal, path

I wrote a simple test module example, 2 files, test.module, test.info, and enabled them in drupal 7 modules.

I cleared all the cache, and still when i'm trying to go to localhost/drupal/hello , i get drupal 404 page not found, why is that?

Here is my code:

```
<?php

function test_world_help($section) {
  switch ($section) {
    case 'admin/help#hello_world':
      $output = '<p>Hello world help...</p>';
      return $output;
    case 'admin/modules#description':
      return 'Hello world module description...';
  }
}

function test_world_menu($may_cache) {
  $items = array();

  if ($may_cache) {
  }
  else {
    $items['hello'] = array(
      'title' => 'Hello world page...', 
      'callback' => 'test_world_page', 
      'access' => TRUE, 
      'type' => MENU_CALLBACK 
    );
  }

  return $items;
}

function test_world_page() {
  return '<p>Hello world!</p>';
}
```

Comment: I am confused, what is test_world_page? There is no page hook http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--module.inc/group/hooks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have posted almost the same question [once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7489612/drupal-7-how-i-can-acces-my-module-and-view-admin-page) and [twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510465/what-is-the-path-of-my-module-in-drupal-7) before. Why don't you update the original one instead of posting new ones?

- The hook_menu() does not have the $may_cache argument in Drupal 7. You should remove it. However, it should not solve your problem as it is unset and false. Thus, the $items should still be populated.
- It is correct, as jprofitt says, that you should change 'callback' to 'page callback'.
- There is no such thing as 'access', but there is 'access callback' and 'access arguments'. You are most likely looking for 'access callback'. However, you can't just set it to 'true'. It expects a function name which returns either 'true' or 'false'. It defaults to 'user_access', so you should just leave it that way. However, you might want to set 'access arguments' to something like 'access content'.

Does the following piece of code work better?

```
function test_world_menu() {

  $items = array();

  $items['hello'] = array(
    'title' => 'Hello World!', 
    'page callback' => 'test_world_page', 
    'access arguments' => array('access content'), 
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK 
    );

  return $items;
}
```

It seems that you haven't really had a look at the [documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_menu). I might be wrong. However, the documentation at api.drupal.org is always a good start to look when you want to learn the basics of how something work.

Comment: Hey, i didnt knew how to add comment sorry, I've tried your code, and still get 404 page not found, I have no idea what is wrong :/

Comment: Make sure you use the same module name throughout your entire module. You've written that the module files are test.module while your functions are named test_world_x(). This makes me think wether you've done the same anywhere else? Choose one name, and make sure all files and functions use that name. It makes it so much easier to get an overview of things. Furthermore, disable and enable you module when you make changes to hook_menu, or alternatively clear the cache. If you've still got trouble making it work, then post the .info file here as well.

Comment: Still not working :/ here is the info file.   name = Test module
description = My test module.
package = Test
version = 1.0
core = 7.x

Comment: Hey, now its working :) but i see clear white page, without the string .. i think something missing here..

Comment: Ok not everything is working, the problem was that : my menu function was test_world_menu, i changed it to test_menu and everything is working :)

Comment: Yes, you need to make sure that functions follow the same naming convention as your module. You are welcome to mark my answer as correct if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably change `'callback'` to `'page callback'`, as I don't believe hook_menu() has just a plain "callback" option. And since you're working with Drupal 7, its hook_menu() actually doesn't have parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall and reinstall your custom module. I hope this will help you. Because it's necessary for drupal core to know the newly created path created using hook_menu.